# Copy a DataRow to another table (vb.net / mysql)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatables, dataset

I have a Two identical data tables in my project, One is Purchase Orders and the other is a template datatable. (IE: the user can select a template when creating a new row in the original table.)

A Save Template button runs:

```
Public Shared Sub AddPO_as_Template(Name As String, DR As DataRow)
    Dim ds As New SomeDataSet
    Dim ta As New SomeDataSetDataSetTableAdapters.PurchaseOrderTemplatesTableAdapter
    Try
        DR("Name") = Name
        ds.PurchaseOrderTemplates.ImportRow(DR)
        ta.Update(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        CommonRoutines.ShowExceptionDialog("Could not add the Template, an error occured.", ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This particular code throws a concurrency violation. I assume this is happening because the ID column is auto increment and I as using the origional row's ID.

Now; the ID in the second table (PurchaseOrderTemplates) is not important at all, so it can be anything. I have tried setting -1, dbnull, "", etc.... the DB keeps trowing exceptions on the update command.

How can I reset the ID column so it just adds as normal? (I know i could create a newrow and move all the columns accross, but this seems the long way.)

Thanks

EDIT: Copying the rows (via .itemarray) works fine, but i need to get the auto increment value from the table somehow to avoid concurrency violations.

Edit2: So i got it working as per the answer below, but I'd still love to know how to get import row working like this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Row as follows works.

```
 Public Shared Sub AddPO_as_Template(Name As String, DR As DataRow)
    Dim ds As New SomeDataSet
    Dim ta As New SomeDataSetTableAdapters.PurchaseOrderTemplatesTableAdapter

        Dim NewRow As DataRow
        NewRow = ds.PurchaseOrderTemplates.NewRow
        NewRow.ItemArray = DR.ItemArray
        NewRow("Name") = Name
        NewRow("ID") = 1
        ds.PurchaseOrderTemplates.Rows.Add(NewRow)
        ta.Update(ds)
End Sub
```

The MySQL database ignores the value in the ID column, and just sets its own auto increment value.